# How to specify custom density function for GeoHistogram?

Tags: bugs, geographics, internals

**Bug introduced in 11.0.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

 `GeoHistrogram` is new in 11.0

---

Using `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` on `GeoHistogram` to investigate specifying a custom density function I noticed that it will accept an argument with `Function` head for the *hspec* parameter. However, when called with such a function `GeoHistogram` appears to completely ignore it.

```
SeedRandom[341];
vals = GeoPosition@#[[;; 2]] -> Last@# & /@ 
   RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{-27, 133, 50000}, 
     {{15, -.2, .5}, {-.2, 20, .8}, {.5, .8, 10000}}], 300];
```

Then, for example, if I want the `Max` value in the bin to be the height specification.

```
GeoHistogram[vals, Automatic, Function[{bins, vals}, Max/@vals]]
```

However, this gives an error for the density specification and returns the plot equivalent to if `Automatic` was selected for *hspec*.

How do you specify a custom density function for `GeoHistogram`?  I want to make use of much of the functionality of `GeoHistogram` but use my own density function.

I suspect I have the incorrect number of parameters or am returning an incorrect format from the function that is causing the error.

**Update**: Confirmed bug - [CASE:3719954]

Comment: I think its just a bug.

Comment: @chuy Checking with WRI.

Comment: While waiting I came up with this little nugget: `Block[{Total = Max}, GeoHistogram[vals]]`. It seems to work but is sooo risky that I don't consider it a solution or workaround.